# stream audio using yt-dlp kn python instead of downloading the file

Tags: discord.py, ytdl

i want to stream audio for a discord bot instead of downloading the file and extracting the audio file from it. i have tried code from [Is there a way to directly stream audio from a youtube video using youtube-dl or pafy library in python 3.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745020/is-there-a-way-to-directly-stream-audio-from-a-youtube-video-using-youtube-dl-or)

Answer (score 2):

Yes Simple

1. Install yt_dlp
2. Import it

Use This Code :

```
ffmpeg_options = {'options': '-vn'}
ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio'}
with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    song_info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)

ctx.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song_info["url"], **ffmpeg_options))
```

Example:

```
async def streamx(ctx, url):
voiceChannel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel //get Message Sender Channel. When you want it to join without a seperat function.
await voiceChannel.connect() //same applies to this
ffmpeg_options = {'options': '-vn'}
ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio'}
with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    song_info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)

ctx.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song_info["url"], **ffmpeg_options))
```

You can adapt the ydl_opts with the documentation from yt_dlp.

Greetings!